# Updating your .bashrc profile file to SSH into Bitbucket on Windows

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-bash

I am following [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)  to set up SSH for BitBucket. I got the key generated and got through step four of creating a .bashrc profile file that automatically starts the SSH agent when git bash starts. However, when I restart Git Bash nothing happens. I've checked and the script the .bashrc is in my home folder and matches their instructions. I'm not quite sure where to go from here / why this script is not initiated when I start git bash.

Comment: Does `ssh-add -l` list anything after you restarted Bash?

Comment: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: Ok, some more checks: Could you post the output (if any) of the following commands: `. .bashrc`, `. $(ssh-agent)`, `ssh-add`, `ssh-add -l`.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure `HOME` is set to `%USERPROFILE%`, before starting git bash (in case git bash does not set it up itself).

Then, make sure (again before opening Git Bash) that your `%PATH%` includes `<git>` and `<git>\usr\bin`, with '`<git>`' being the Git installation path.
That usr/bin subfolder did not exist with the old Git 1.7 used at the time of the BitBucket documentation.
Make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.12)